# Can a signed double submit cookie CSRF token be a JWT?

Tags: jwt

I was reading about the naive and signed double submit cookie implementation from [this OWASP section](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie) and was wondering if I could just use the same JWT plumbing to create and verify the CSRF token as I would the authentication token? Based on their suggestions, here is what I'm planning:

- When I generate the authentication token, I add a claim that is just a new UUID identifying the session. This token is sent back on a cookie with http only, secure, same-site, the works.
- I create another JWT with only the UUID and a random salt. This is sent back as a normal cookie.
- On a request, I verify both the JWT's, I compare the CSRF cookie and header (just a basic text comparison), and then I compare the UUID claims.

As far as I understand it this hardens against situations where an attacker finds a way to overwrite the CSRF cookie correct? Am I doing anything redundant? I'm not certain I even need the uuid or the check. The main point of my question is whether there is anything I should be concerned about using a JWT as my CSRF token.